# Kendo Grid not displaying JSON MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, razor, kendo-grid

My controller is returning the Json data but instead of populating the Grid it displays as raw Json text. First time using Kendo so I am not sure what I am doing wrong? Is the the grid not being initialized? I have a search form on a cshtml view "reports". I would like  the search results to be displayed on a partial view 'ReportsPhone' or on the 'reports' view itself. I do not know the best way about doing that.

Reports View

```
@model UtilityWebSite.Models.ReportsPhoneSupport
 @{
ViewBag.Title = "Reports";
 }
 <div class="container">
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12 column">
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-4 column">
                <h2>Phone Support Reports </h2>
                <div>
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("ReportsPhoneSupport", "Reports"))
                    {
                        <div>
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserId)<br />
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserId, new { @class = "k-textbox" }) <br />
                        </div><br />

                        <div>
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FromDate)<br />
                            <div>@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(model => model.FromDate))</div><br />

                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ToDate)<br />
                            <div>@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(model => model.ToDate))</div>
                            <br />
                            <input type="submit" class="k-button" value="Submit" />
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 column">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 column">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Reports Controller

```
[Authorize]
public class ReportsController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Reports()
    {
        ReportsPhoneSupport model = new ReportsPhoneSupport();
        model.ToDate = DateTime.Parse("05/14/2014");
        //do 
        //{
        //    TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now - model.ToDate;
        //    if (span.TotalDays < 2) break;
        //    model.ToDate = model.ToDate.AddDays(14);
        //}
        //while (model.ToDate < DateTime.Now);
        model.FromDate = model.ToDate.AddDays(-14);
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ReportsPhoneSupport()
    {

        return PartialView();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult ReportsPhoneSupport([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ReportsPhoneSupport model)
    {
        string[] userIds = model.UserId.Split(',');
        ReportPhoneSupportResultTypedView results = new ReportPhoneSupportResultTypedView();
        foreach (string userId in userIds)
        {
            int iUserId = 0;
            if (Int32.TryParse(userId, out iUserId))
            {

                RetrievalProcedures.FetchReportPhoneSupportResultTypedView(results, model.FromDate, model.ToDate, iUserId);
            }
        }
        var Results = from Reslt in results
                      select new
                      {
                          ActivityDate = Reslt.ActivityDate,
                          Action = Reslt.Action,
                          Assignment = Reslt.Assignment,
                          Description = Reslt.Description,
                          Result = Reslt.Result,
                          ToFrom = Reslt.ToFrom
                      };
        return Json(Results.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

ReportsPhone Partial View

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12 column">
        <div class="row clearfix">
            @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ZoomAudits.DAL.TypedViewClasses.ReportPhoneSupportResultRow>()
.Name("grid")

.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(m => m.ActivityDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Title("Activity Date");
    columns.Bound(m => m.Assignment).Title("Assignment");
    columns.Bound(m => m.Action).Title("Action");
    columns.Bound(m => m.ToFrom).Title("ToFrom");
    columns.Bound(m => m.Result).Title("Result");
    columns.Bound(m => m.Description).Title("Description");
})

//.AutoBind(true)
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Scrollable()
.Filterable()

.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .ServerOperation(true)
    .PageSize(20)
    // .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Assignment))
    .Read(read => read.Action("ReportsPhoneSupport", "Reports"))
 )
            )
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sample Json text

```
{"Data":[{"ActivityDate":"\/Date(1398866129000)\/","Action":"Call Placed","Assignment":9538,"Description":"Spoke with insured,
```

Comment: Is the Grid sending a GET call back to the controller? And it is returning nothing? how does this work? How does the grid initialize? I have never used this before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CONTROLLER

```
{
[Authorize]
public class ReportsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Reports()
    {
        ReportsPhoneSupportSearchVM model = new ReportsPhoneSupportSearchVM();
        model.ToDate = DateTime.Parse("05/14/2014");
        //do 
        //{
        //    TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now - model.ToDate;
        //    if (span.TotalDays < 2) break;
        //    model.ToDate = model.ToDate.AddDays(14);
        //}
        //while (model.ToDate < DateTime.Now);
        model.FromDate = model.ToDate.AddDays(-14);
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ReportSearchResults(ReportsPhoneSupportSearchVM model)
    {

        return PartialView(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ReportsPhoneSupportRead([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ReportsPhoneSupportSearchVM model)
    {

        ReportPhoneSupportResultTypedView results = new ReportPhoneSupportResultTypedView();
        string[] userIds = model.UserId.Split(',');
        foreach (string userId in userIds)
        {
            int iUserId = 0;
            if (Int32.TryParse(userId, out iUserId))
            {

                RetrievalProcedures.FetchReportPhoneSupportResultTypedView(results, model.FromDate, model.ToDate, iUserId);
            }
        }

        var Results = from Reslt in results
                      select new
                      {
                          ActivityDate = Reslt.ActivityDate,
                          Action = Reslt.Action,
                          Assignment = Reslt.Assignment,
                          Description = Reslt.Description,
                          Result = Reslt.Result,
                          ToFrom = Reslt.ToFrom
                      };
        return Json(Results.ToDataSourceResult(request));
        //return Json(Results.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

}
}
```

SearchView

```
@model UtilityWebSite.Models.ReportsPhoneSupportSearchVM
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Reports";
}
<div class="container">
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12 column">
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-4 column">
                <h2>Phone Support Reports </h2>
                <div>
                    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("ReportSearchResults", "Reports", new   AjaxOptions
                    {
                      UpdateTargetId = "searchResult"
                    }))

                    {
                        <div>
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserId)<br />
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserId, new { @class = "k-textbox" }) <br />
                        </div><br />
                        <div>
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FromDate)<br />
                            <div>@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(model => model.FromDate))</div><br />

                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ToDate)<br />
                            <div>@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(model => model.ToDate))</div>
                            <br />
                            <input type="submit" class="k-button" value="Submit" />
                        </div>
                    }
```

SearchResultsPartialView

```
@model UtilityWebSite.Models.ReportsPhoneSupportSearchVM

 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ZoomAudits.DAL.TypedViewClasses.ReportPhoneSupportResultRow>()
.Name("grid")

.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(m => m.ActivityDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Title("Activity Date");
    columns.Bound(m => m.Assignment).Title("Assignment");
    columns.Bound(m => m.Action).Title("Action");
    columns.Bound(m => m.ToFrom).Title("ToFrom");
    columns.Bound(m => m.Result).Title("Result");
    columns.Bound(m => m.Description).Title("Description");
})
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Scrollable()
.Filterable()
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(20)
    .Read(read => read.Action("ReportsPhoneSupportRead", "Reports", Model))
 )
 )
```